# How can I automatically create an ID in the program? (The program works with files)

Tags: c#

I wrote a program that does work with files like delete and update, store, and search And all customers,My code to create an ID automatically for each line of the file, but I do not know the way I have done what is right.Is there a better way to do this?

That is the way I read the entire file into a variable, and the last line of the file will then be Find and ID the line number plus one, and then I return

[**Project Files**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy6rp1rghyqjrs8/CoustomersApp.rar)

[**Video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reQLqKRanKY&feature=youtu.be)

**Code methode CreateAutomicId in class BaseDataAccess:**

```
   public virtual int CreateAutomicId()
    {
        var alldata = FRepository.LoadAll();
        var lastline = alldata.Last().Split(',');
        var fetchId = Convert.ToInt32(lastline[0]);

        var plusId = fetchId + 1;

        return plusId;
    }
```

Comment: This definitely isn't thread-safe.  Will multiple instances be accessing this repository simultaneously?  If so, they might calculate the same "next ID" at the same time.  If the underlying data source doesn't have a way to track this (such as an identity field in a database table) then maybe use a `System.Guid` as an identifier?

Comment: [System.Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) is the way to go for sure.

Comment: Just going out on a limb here and saying that this is a school project @David they probably don't care about thread safety at this point....

Comment: I have to agree with @Mike that generating a GUID is your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution definitely isn't thread-safe, and if multiple instances tried to calculate the "next ID" at the same time then they can easily collide.

**Does the underlying data source have a way to track this?**

In the vast majority of cases, that's the preferred approach.  For example, in a database you can have an identity column in which the inner workings of the database itself maintain the uniqueness of the next value.  The code you write wouldn't supply the underlying system with an identity, it would be told by the underlying system what the next identity is.

If that's not a possibility...

**Does the identity need to be an integer?**

If it doesn't, then [`System.Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) is a ready source of unique identifiers.  Using that would obviate the need for this entire function, since all you'd need to generate your next ID is:

```
var nextID = Guid.NewGuid();
```

If it *does* need to be an integer, then...

**Does the identity need to be sequential?**

You can still create a `Guid` and convert it into a *very* unique (though I suppose [not *as unique* as a `Guid`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx)) integer using `.GetHashCode()`.  If you don't need to save the `Guid` at all, it might be something as simple as:

```
var nextID = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
```

Or, in the context of your function:

```
public virtual int CreateAutomicId()
{
    return Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
}
```

Using a `Guid` would also remove the dependency on *reading* from the data source in order to generate the "next" identifier, which reduces I/O bottlenecks.

Comment: Couldn't he just write-lock the global index file before creating the number and then adding it back into the file?

Comment: Is it possible to sort the GUID?

Comment: @ebyrob: Possibly, depending on the implementation.  That may also just replace collisions with errors.  Which is actually preferred, since code failing quickly and loudly is vastly better than subtle and silent bugs (which may happen with collisions, depending on what the rest of the system does with these identifiers).

Comment: @objectjson: Guids aren't sequential, so they're not meant for sorting.  (There *are* supposedly "sequential guid" algorithms out there, but I've never met one I've liked.)  Without knowing more about the functionality being achieved, it's difficult to advise.  In cases where Guids are used for uniqueness, they're essentially *only* used for uniqueness, not other properties (such as ordering).  Sorting can happen on other data elements, though.  In fact it's usually a design smell when non-system use cases (display order, for example) rely on the object's system identifier.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this:

First one is using NewGuid() function that is in the System namespace and under the Guid class.

The second way is that you can use date and time. What I mean is you can concatenate Year, month, day, hour, second and milisecond together, at that way, you would be able to follow the date of the id generating process and generate unique Id based on miliseconds.

The Last one is Ticks in DateTime object. It is fairly useful. It generates unique Int-64 size number which is my favorite way to do same thing. You can use it like : DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()

I hope these optoins will help you.